# Javascript animation is skewed when it runs fast

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've just created a simple animation function that moves a box from left to right. The problem is when the animation runs the box becomes a rectangle when it animates so the proportion of the box shape is gone which is not what I want, how can you retain the shape of the box through the animation. When you slow the animation down to 2 seconds the box retains its shape but when you speed up the animation then it becomes skewed. How do you prevent this from happening?

```js
function animate(...args) {
  let starttime = new Date().getTime();
  let requestID;
  
  if(args.length == 5) {
    args = { el: args[0], props: args[1], duration: args[2], step: args[3], callback: args[4] };
  } else {
    args = { el: args[0], props: args[1], duration: args[2], callback: args[3] };
  }  
  
  function moveit(args) {
    var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    var runtime = timestamp - starttime;
    var progress = runtime / args.duration;
    
    progress = Math.min(progress, 1);
    
    for(const prop in args.props) {
      let dist = parseInt(args.props[prop].substring(0, args.props[prop].length - 2), 10);
      args.el.style[prop] = (dist * progress).toFixed(2) + 'px';        
    }
    
    if(args.step != undefined) {
      args.step(progress);
    }
    
    if (runtime < args.duration){ // if duration not met yet
      requestID = requestAnimationFrame(moveit.bind(new Date().getTime(), args));
    } else {  
      args.callback();
      cancelAnimationFrame(requestID);        
    }
  }
  
  requestAnimationFrame(moveit.bind(new Date().getTime(), args));
}


window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
  //alert('Hello World')
  
  document.getElementById('reset')
    .addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    document.getElementById('box').setAttribute('style', '')
  });
  
  document.getElementById('play')
    .addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      animate(document.getElementById('box'), { left: '400px' }, 500, function(step) {

    }, function() {

    });

  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.controls {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="box"></div>

<div class="controls">
  <button id="reset">reset</button>
  <button id="play">play</button>
</div>
```

Comment: On my computer (+Firefox), I don't see it skewed at all, even if I set the time to 0.1 sec, it renders very well. I have a decent graphic card, and a i7 6 cores, if that matters.

Comment: @Pac0 thanks for letting me know, it could be because my laptop is shitty with a bad graphics card

Comment: yes, that's probably linked with the capabilities of the client machine. I'm not sure there is much you can do here. Maybe try to use css animations? With a bit of luck, they' re better optimized than some custom javascript code that one writes? Check for instance here: https://freefrontend.com/css-animation-examples/ . There is one called "Motion blur" that is similar to your one (a square moving right and left).